# How to Open .dist extension as folder on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, java, eclipse

I'am currently developing Java application with Eclipse IDE and having this folder named "workspace.dist". This contains the deployed portlet to be deployed to a framework. Now my problem is, Mac OS recognizes workspace.dist as TextMate extension (a text editor). For the mean time, I had to "Show Package Content" thru context menu to open this file.

So my question is if there a way to associate .dist extension as Finder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. Quit TextMate and open `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Info.plist` in a text editor.
2. Remove the highlighted content from line 531 per the screenshot below:

   [image]
3. Log out and back in.

Comment: I did what you'd instructed but the "workspace.dist" still associated with TextMate.

Comment: @Erize It should have worked… Reboot?

Comment: I already did rebooting the OS but still no good. I've also already searched keywoard "dist" inside the TextMate's Info.plist and it has no result so I don't know why dist extension still associated with TextMate.